# format() int as float

Tags: python, format

I'm wondering if it have a way to do what I want.

Using `format` string built-in method, it's possible to print a float as an int :

```
some_float = 1234.5678
print '%02d' % some_float  # 1234
```

It's also possible to do that by extending the class [string.Formatter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.Formatter):

```
class MyFormatter(Formatter):
    def format_field(self, value, format_spec):
        if format_spec == 't':  # Truncate and render as int
            return str(int(value))
        return super(MyFormatter, self).format_field(value, format_spec)

MyFormatter().format("{0}{1:t}", "", 1234.567)  # returns "1234"
```

### What I want to do

I want to print an int as a float :

```
some_int = 12345678
print '{WHAT?}'.format(some_int) # I want 1234.5678
print '{WHAT ELSE?}'.format(some_int) # I want 123456.78
```

Do you have any idea to how to do this ?

Using `format` or anything else but keep in mind that **I do not know in advance the number of decimal digits**

Comment: Can't you print float(some_int)/1e4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can divide your number by 10000 or 100:

```
some_int = 12345678
print '{0:.4f}'.format(some_int / 10000.0)
print '{0:.2f}'.format(some_int / 100.0)
```

or with a variable amount of decimals:

```
decimals = 3
print '{0:.{1}f}'.format(some_int / 10.0**decimals, decimals)
```

Comment: Yep but if I don't know the number of decimal digits in advance ?